# C# Timer only running once, when ran from class method

Tags: c#, timer, callback

This is a video class that has a method `Play()` that simply just creates a timer with the interval of 1 second, but it seems to only execute the callback function once!

```
class VideoPost : Post
    {
        private int counter;
        private Timer timer;
        protected int Duration;
        protected string VideoUrl;

        public VideoPost(string title, string user, int duration, string videoUrl): base(title, user)
        {
            Duration = duration;
            VideoUrl = videoUrl;
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Playing video");
            timer = new Timer(TimerCallBack, null, 0, 1000);
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            timer.Dispose();
            if (counter < Duration)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Video stopped at {0}s", counter);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Video has ended");
            }
        }

        private void TimerCallBack(Object o)
        {
            if (counter < Duration)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Video is at {0}s", counter);
                counter++;
            } else
            {
                Stop();
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Post - {0}, {1} written by {2}, Video -> {3} of the length {4}", Id, Title, User, VideoUrl, Duration);
        }
    }
```

This is it being called

```
VideoPost newVideoPost = new VideoPost("video of my fortnite montage", "damilola jerugba", 10, "https://www.video.com/montage.mp4");

Console.WriteLine(newVideoPost.ToString());

newVideoPost.Play();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show this, but presumably you have some other code which keeps `VideoPost` alive, for along enough for the timer to execute again? And indeed, long enough to keep your application from exiting!

Comment: What does your output look like?

Comment: @ragerory it just says `Playing video` then ends the program

Comment: If there is no code after newVideoPost.Play() that keeps the program alive then yes the program will end.

Comment: @Ralf i just added a `Console.ReadKey()` and it works now, but why doesn't it just start the timer then end the program when the program ends

Comment: That simply how such things work. The life time of your main thread determines the lifetime of your program. Other threads will be killed then. More concrete there is a distinction between foreground and background threads. The main thread started by your program is a foreground thread the timer starts a background thread. And when no foreground thread is running anymore the program end.

Comment: @Ralf thanks a lot I get it now!